# Issue when adding Multiprocessing to a function with a return in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I recently put a post on Stack Overflow, but it wasn't enough information, so it got closed.

Because I did some more research, and more trial and error and also got help from my original post
I am trying to post it again, and see if I have more luck.

I am using **Jupyter Notebook** on **64 bit Windows machine** using **Python3**.

I am trying to add multi processing to a for loop in python, So that instead of the code looking at one item at a time and appending to a tmplist **which is an array, that will eventually be converted to a data frame**, it should run multiple times for different values, making it go quicker.

I replaced the for loop to be a function. Instead of saying
**for StockId id in ArrId**, I replaced it with **def AddToTable(StockId)** and return the record from the tmplist. I want to add Multiprocessing, and then add all the returns from tmplist into an array so that I can have all the returns in one array.

```py
   

    import numpy as np
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    import multiprocessing 
        
    ArrId=[2345,1234,234532,4532,3464532,245345456,34534,234323,4524]
    tmplist = []
    
    def AddToTable(StockID):
        return tmplist.append(StockId)


#(If you run this - you will see what is returned)

    for StockId in ArrId:
        AddToTable(StockId)
    print(tmplist)

#Then I added multi processing (see below), but the block of code never finishes.

     if __name__ == '__main__':
    
            jobs = []
            with multiprocessing.Pool() as p: 
                    results=p.map(AddToTable,ArrId)
                    jobs.append(results)
                    p.close()
                    p.join()
        
#**Any help will be appreciated!**
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation in the question and provide more details and elaborate on the question? It's unclear.

Comment: @user17313372 No. Your AddToTable function is syntactically incorrect. Also, when you've fixed it, it will not iterate over List.iterrows as it will return after the first item. If iterrows is effectively empty the function will return None. Also p.close and p.join make no sense

Comment: @BrutusForcus - the function works on my side because it connects to the database and pulls those values.. If there is a way to get this idea to work... I will be grateful

Comment: 1: Using `with Pool() as p:` makes your `try: except:` block redundant. That's what `with` does. 2: what is `tmplist`? if it's a regular python list, you try to return the result of `append`, which is always `None`. 3: when using `Process` rather than `Pool`, you need to send any data you want back to the main process explicitly using something like a `mp.Pipe` or `mp.Queue`. `return`  values do not get passed along (Pool just has code to do this for you).

Comment: 4: what version of python are you using? what OS are you using? what IDE are you using? These are unfortunately very important to multiprocessing.

Comment: edited my post - please can you take a look?

Comment: Sorry, but the code is a mess; please [edit] it to bring it into shape. The indentation is all over the place. ``Availability`` and ``tmplist`` are not defined. ``list.append`` returns ``None``, so ``return tmplist.append([row['StockID']])`` isn't sensible *and* breaks the loop. ``Pool.map`` runs *all* jobs at once, so ``jobs.append(results)`` just needlessly wraps *the single* result into a list. Most critically, the use-case presented just is not suitable for multiprocessing – it looks like you are making a selection on a numpy array, which is *already* internally parallel. ...

Comment: ... Duplicating such data over many processes to run a trivial operation will make things *worse*: duplication means copying the entire data, which is very expensive, while a trivial operation does not benefit much from parallelism. *If* your actual use-case is more suitable for multiprocessing, please provide some details on it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi- to confirm - if I have a for loop that appends data to an array, which will be converted to a dataframe- it is not worth adding multiprocessing, so that the loop will run faster- because the downside of appending to a new array outweighs the pro of multiprocessing?

Comment: Logically though- it should take quicker- to run simultaneously, and just append a single row.. I would like to implement and see. Any help with fixing the code would be appreciated. The reason why the function doesn't work on your end, is because this is connecting to my database.. You just ignore the two first lines of the AddToTable function for testing purposes

Comment: *Running* simultaneously is quicker, but it has to actually *copy* the data before doing that. Either way, the function doesn't work on my end because there are significant parts missing and what is there is badly formatted. Even if your real code connects to a database to get data, that should not stop you from supplying some fixed, literal data in your [mre]; it's very important to do so because having and handling data is not for free with ``multiprocessing``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - thank you for pointing that out. I updated the code to have a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Mister @Aaron- if you have a chance can you take a look and see?